# How to POST DATA to api in Android using RubyMotion

Tags: post, rubymotion

I am trying to post `userName` and `password` to API, here is my code:

```
params = {"Username" => "testagent@yopmail.com" , "password" => "123@asAS", "grant_type" => "password"}
    get=Com::Android::Volley::Toolbox::JsonObjectRequest.new(VolleyMethods::POST, url, self, nil)
    data=Com::Android::Volley::Toolbox::Volley.newRequestQueue(self).add(get)
```

It is not working can anyone help me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post any errors you are getting.

Comment: Ignoring line: RegisterActivity : android.app.Activity <com.android.volley.Response.ErrorListener,com.android.volley.Response.Listener<T>>
Method declaration outside class definition